# Launch Screen.storyboard not work properly Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9

I am using Launch Screen storyboard in Xcode 7 to support iOS 9, And using imageSet to support iOS 7.

First thing I put `UIImageView` in LaunchView at full screen, and use images below (see image) at source to that imageView , but when I run my app in simulator this image do not show correctly (iPhone 4s, 5, 6, and 6 plus)

[image]

Where is the problem?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have faced same issue one time. batter to use **xcassets**

For the launch image you can use the assets folder with the device specific launch images.

[image]

Add all launch screen here as per your requirement.

**Go to the General Settings Of your project and check your settings make sure you have selected the assets folder. Remove the Launch Screen File text.**

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this has solved the problem, only worked around it. By replacing the launch storyboard with launch images, there will be problems in a couple of weeks when the new iPad Pro is release. Launch storyboards exist to avoid having a separate image for every single screen size. I don't think we have been given enough information by the OP to answer the question.

Comment: Does iOS 7 supports Launchscreen storyboard? When create a sample application i get black screen.

Comment: @RosAng Launchscreen storyboard is supported from iOS 8 and above, for iOS 7 you need to add Launch Images.

Answer (score 1):

Add all the images in Assets.xcassets as per expected size . Otherwise add image view in Launchscreen.storyboard and apply autoLayout.