# Black Screen with iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9

I had developed Application in Xcode 6.2, and now I am running this app in Xcode 7.0.1 and this giving me this type of output.

> How to make the the application which is compatible on all device
>   including iPhone 6S and iPhone 6S Plus with iOS 9.

How to solve this issue ?

[image]

Comment: Just add launchscreens in your project. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945903/launch-screen-storyboard-not-work-properly-xcode-7/32945986#32945986 Hope it helps you.

Comment: just Added lunch screen for iphone 6s &iphone 6splus

Comment: I don't want to do anything with launch screen, This is happens with all screen of my projects

Comment: check this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964581/ios-9-objective-c-screen-size-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had developed your project in Xcode 6.2, So in your project there is no such file LaunchScreen.Storyboard.

> Targets -> General -> Launch Screen File -> Choose your -> Main.Storyboard

Now, run the project.

[image: chanange]

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 7 there were changes in launch screen so you need to update in launch screen.storyboard. Otherwise change deployment target .

Comment: can you elaborate how ?

Comment: check in storyboard are you working with auto layout?

Comment: yes. .. I am working with autolayout, and I had changed deployment target to 9.0 still its not working

Comment: Ok. check with orientation of devices.. make deployment target to 8.0

Comment: @Florence if you need to know how to add a launch screen my answer may help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was resolved by adding a launch screen.
If you already have a launch screen see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964581/ios-9-objective-c-screen-size-issues) answer.

If you don't already have a launch screen, I believe Apple recommends that you should have one and here are [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html) step-by-step instructions on how to add one:

Adding an iOS App Icon Set or Launch Image Set

Organize different resolutions of your app icons and launch images using image sets.

Select an asset catalog.

Choose Editor > Add Assets > App Icons & Launch Images > New iOS App Icon.

[image]

An empty app icon set is created, with an image well for each image representation in the set.

Drag an app icon from the Finder to the appropriate image well in the set viewer.
   [image]

Alternatively, you can add app icons by selecting an asset catalog, and then choosing Editor > Add Assets > Import.

To add a launch image set, choose Editor > Add Assets > App Icons & Launch Images > New Launch Image and follow the steps described above, substituting launch images for app icons. Instead of a set of launch images, if your app targets at least iOS 8 you can use one launch screen file. This is a xib file that can adapt to any screen size or orientation. For more information, see [Creating a Launch Screen File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW4).